# uEye camera in ROS

Tags: ros, ueye-cam, ueye, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to setup an uEye USB camera in ROS. I already installed the official drivers, and the camera is working correctly.

For ROS integration, I found two references:

http://ros.org/wiki/ueye

It only supports IS_CM_BGR8_PACKED format, so no color images available.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ueye_cam

Seems more complete than the previous one, but the pointer to the repository is missing and I am not able to find it.

Can someone point me out where to find the package *ueye_cam* ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58680/ueye-camera-in-ros/) by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wendyZzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26319/wendyzzzz/) on 2016-04-07**:
Hi . can I asking you how did you install the official driver ?  I read through the instruction but I really can't follow it . Would you mind to tell me how you install your driver ? Thank you very much !!!!!

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-07**:
Are you using a pylon camera?

**Comment by [Danfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/59651/danfo/) on 2020-10-19**:
@NEngelhard you can look at this website https://de.ids-imaging.com/downloads.html, to find your right cmaera model driver. but you have to register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's up now (it was previously in limbo for various reasons). I can't post links, so just check the ROS wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [anqixu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4772/anqixu/) with karma: 193 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1